# What do MacBook Pro 2020 model codes mean?

Tags: macbook-pro

I found several codes of current MacBook Pro 16” models. What do these codes mean? I plan to buy a new MB Pro 16” in late 2020-beginning 2021 and I’m in a bit of confusion how to read these codes, what model should I choose. I want as the latest model as possible. Late 2020 or early 2021.

Z0XZ006V9
Z0XZ006WV
Z0XZ006X3
Z0XZ006VC
Z0XZ006WT

Z0XZ008LG
Z0XZ008LE
Z0XZ008LJ

Comment: Just before Apple announce [Nov 17 estimated] the new lineup of Macs for next year  is not the time to be thinking of buying a new last-year's model. Wait. In a month you can either have last year's cheaper, or the new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin I somehow missed out this announcement. Thanks. However rumors go that Apple won’t introduce new MB Pro 16” with its own ARM-based Apple Silicon chip at this update. Only 13” versions and Macs. Hope they will 

Answer (score 2):

There's no 2020 or 2021 model of the 16" MacBook Pro currently. The 16" MacBook Pro only exists as the Late 2019 model - there are no others.

The codes you have refer to various build-to-order variants. For example you can buy the 16" model with 16 GB RAM, 32 GB or 64 GB RAM, there's 3 different CPU models, 3 GPU variants, 5 SSD sizes, and so on.